# Warmup Request Error of Django app on GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

My Django app on GAE is throwing an error warming request, which I cannot understand.
When I manually type **www.mydomainname.com/_ah/warmup** I get 404 error, but that's normal.
Where should I start debugging for this? Below is the error message.

```
E 2013-10-15 18:26:19.551
Internal Server Error: /_ah/warmup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/middleware/common.py", line 57, in process_request
    host = request.get_host()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/http/request.py", line 72, in get_host
    "Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): %s" % host)
SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): 1.myappname.appspot.com

2013-10-15 18:26:22.030
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 224, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/views/defaults.py", line 41, in server_error
    return http.HttpResponseServerError(template.render(Context({})))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 124, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 285, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/templatetags/cache.py", line 29, in render
    key = ':'.join([urlquote(resolve_variable(var, context)) for var in self.vary_on])
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 659, in resolve_variable
    return Variable(path).resolve(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 728, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/template/base.py", line 771, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [user] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {}]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your settings.conf file, you need to add:

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ('.myappname.appspot.com',)

More info here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: Actually for GAE you can safely use: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
GAE's safety features guarantee that doing so is secure. You can see it in this sample from Google: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/django/mysite/settings.py